# Foundation - Icon Bar: <label> inside <a> validation issue

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to build the [Icon Bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/icon-bar.html) with the Foundation framework. The suggested, official way is:

```
<a class="item">
  <img src="../assets/img/images/fi-home.svg" >
  <label>Home</label>
</a>
```

I want to use Font Awesome icons and did this:

```
<a class="item" href="http://localhost/">
  <i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
  <label>Home</label>
</a>
```

When checking this code in the Validator I get the error message: **The element label must not appear as a descendant of the a element.**

What can I do to fix this while keeping the functionality? Thanks!

Comment: The suggested, official way is wrong (as is font awesome's use of italic nothing to put a background image on).

Comment: My guess for the reasoning is that a `<label for=` is expected to trigger the e.g. checkbox or radiobutton it labels when interacted, so that naturally would collide with being in the interactable area of a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like foundation is using HTML structure that is not 100 valid. You can use

```
 <a class="item" href="http://localhost/">
  <i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
  <span class="label">Home</span>
</a>
```

and update the css to make sure it looks like the label

or leave it as is and tell foundation to fix it..

Comment: Issue is already reported in official repo: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/5896 but marked as closed

Answer (score 0):

[Probably] Complete set of `.label` styles in **.scss** file would be:

```
.icon-bar {
  .label {
    display: block;
    color: $icon-bar-font-color;
    font-size: $form-label-font-size;
    background: $icon-bar-bg;

    &:hover {
      color: $icon-bar-font-color-hover;
    }
  }
  .active .label {
    background: $icon-bar-hover-color;
  }
}
```

This solution assumes that you have all Foundation variables available in this .scss file.

For above styles using:

```
<a class="item" href="http://localhost/">
  <i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
  <span class="label">Home</span>
</a>
```

Will give desired effect.